# How to write a query to get

Tags: mongodb, collections, database

I have following collection with me from MongoDB:

```
{ "results": [
    {
        "isExist": true,
        "isJourneyEnd": true,
        "objectId": "9WtZcxWttk",
        "sentTo": [
            "JeLRe4yH9R"
        ],
    },
    {
        "isExist": false,
        "isJourneyEnd": true,
        "objectId": "9WtZcxWtul",
        "sentTo": [
            "JeLRe4y9HU"
        ],
    }
]}
```

In actual, there are many entries in this collection, I've just mentioned two.

If I want to write a query for following statement:

"Print element of array whose **isExist** is true".

I would like to have some guidance over this, as I am new to MongoDB.

Comment: which element you want to print? Explain the question clearly.

Comment: Hi Nishant, thanks for your time. I want to write a query which will give me element/s from collection satisfying following sentence:

'Find element/s from collection whose isExist is true'.

And as said above, 'results' is an array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
db.collection.find({isExist: true});
```

Comment: Thanks Gijs & John for your time.
I have tried it, but unfortunately it didn't work for me.
Additionally, I have tried $elemMatch too, which too didn't give me expected data.